# linux/unix tree diagram

Tags: directory, cygwin, tree

I have a picture of a tree diagram for linux/unix terminal. [image: the partial tree diagram, assume your username is lab4aand your current (and home) directory is /Labs/lab4a]

Just to verify the color scheme, all the blue labels must be folders, the greens are executable,  but what are the black ones? Right under "security" and "richmondhill" there are a few files, are they text documents?

(ps, im using cygwin64 terminal to emulate linux/unix terminal in windows, so the tree command doesnt work, thats why im posting this question)

Comment: They are example files from [the coursework for ULI101 at Seneca College](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4206/).

Comment: `tree` works fine in cygwin, what's wrong with yours?

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR:** The black ones are *regular files*.  (Probably.)  This is a unix concept that isn't dependent on the file contents: it merely means it's not a "special file" (a pipe, device, socket, directory, etc).

---

By default `tree`'s colorization follows `$LS_COLORS`, if set, and provides a builtin default if not.  (`$TREE_COLORS`, if set, overrides `$LS_COLORS`; I assume they use the same format.)  The `dircolors` command can be used to print a default setting; see [`man 5 dir_colors`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/dir_colors) for the full format (also [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/94306/222377) for more about the color format).

On my system `dircolors` provides the following definition (newlines and comments added for clarity).

```
# starts with various filetypes (as in dir_colors manpage)
# these filetypes have nothing to do with filename, only attributes
# "di" = directory, "so" = socket,
# "ex" = executable (has 'x' permission set)
# etc
LS_COLORS='rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35
 :bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41
 :tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32

 # colors based on filename matching
 # various archive extensions
 :*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31
 :*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31
 :*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31
 :*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31
 :*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31
 :*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31
 :*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31
 :*.cab=01;31

 # various video extensions     
 :*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35
 :*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35
 :*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35
 :*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35
 :*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35
 :*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35
 :*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35
 :*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35
 :*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35

 # various audio extensions
 :*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36
 :*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36
 :*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36

 # end
 :';
```

---

So, assuming your output is from `tree` with default color output, all we can say about these black-colored files is that they are *regular files with no execute permission set*.  The data in those files could be MP3 data -- if the filename doesn't end in `.mp3`, `tree` won't color it like an MP3 file.