# How to change bash completion result coloring

Tags: bash, autocomplete, manjaro

How to change completion coloring when auto-completing subcommands in bash?[image]

For unknown reason, it looks like the completion results are treated by bash as broken symlinks. And it looks really disturbing.

System info:

- Bash version: 4.4.23(1)-release
- OS: Manjaro Linux

---

Edit: I understand that by setting off the `colored-stats` GNU Readline option in `~/.inputrc` the coloring will be turned off altogether:

```
set colored-stats off
```

But that would also disable other coloring, such as for directory, when auto-completing.

I think this is weird because the broken-symlink-like coloring happens on my Manjaro Linux box at home, but not my Arch Linux box at work. Both are applied with the same `bashrc` and `inputrc`. But I didn't check for other potential difference for now.

---

Edit again: Pasting my `~/.inputrc` for reference:

```
$include /etc/inputrc
$if mode=emacs
# cycle through possible completions
TAB: menu-complete
# complete until the end of common prefix before cycling through possible completions
set menu-complete-display-prefix on
# show possible completions if more than one completions are possible
set show-all-if-ambiguous on
set show-all-if-unmodified on
# do not duplicate characters after the cursor if they consist partially of possbile completion
set skip-completed-text on
# display colors when doing completion as `ls` does
set colored-stats on
# color tab-completion matched prefix part
set colored-completion-prefix on
# fuck off stty key bindings. (stty -a)
set bind-tty-special-chars off
"\C-w": unix-word-rubout
"\eh": kill-region
"\eH": copy-region-as-kill
"\C-x\'": "\'\'\C-b"
"\C-x`": "``\C-b"
"\C-x\"": "\"\"\C-b"
"\C-x{": "{}\C-b"
"\C-x[": "[]\C-b"
"\C-x(": "()\C-b"
"\C-x0": vi-eWord
"\eF": "\C-x0\C-f"
"\eB": vi-bWord
"\eD": "\e \eF\eh"
$endif
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand this as well. My assumption is that something in the way it presents the output is assuming that it's a local file and so is treating it as "missing", but I don't know why yet. It would be good if it just showed them as plain text!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Completion coloring for GNU Readline is enabled with `colored-stats` in `.inputrc`, like you've mentioned.

The colors are determined by `$LS_COLORS`, which can be generated with `dircolors`.

The completion suggestions seem to inherit their colors from the `MISSING` attribute in `~/.dircolors`. Commenting it out (or changing to something less disturbing, e.g. removing `05;` to disable blinking) prints the suggestions in default colors. The corresponding entry in `$LS_COLORS` is `...:mi=03;31:...` (an example with ANSI colors `03` and `31`).

Similar discussion:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1648170

References:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Readline#Colorized_completion
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_output_in_console#ls
[dircolors: modify color settings globaly](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94299/dircolors-modify-color-settings-globaly/94306#94306)
https://askubuntu.com/questions/466198/how-do-i-change-the-color-for-directories-with-ls-in-the-console